# MySQL: How to insert values in a table which has two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using MySQL with NodeJS and i have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keycomponent`.`Transaction` (
  `TransactionID` INT NOT NULL,
  `TransactionDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Amount` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TransactionDescriptionPK` INT NOT NULL,
  `FilePK` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TransactionID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `TransactionID_UNIQUE` (`TransactionID` ASC),
  INDEX `FilePK_idx` (`FilePK` ASC),
  INDEX `TransactionDescriptionPK_idx` (`TransactionDescriptionPK` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `TransactionDescriptionPK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TransactionDescriptionPK`)
    REFERENCES `keycomponent`.`TransactionDescription` (`TransactionDescriptionPK`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FilePK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FilePK`)
    REFERENCES `keycomponent`.`File` (`Filename`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

it contains two foreign keys and when i try to insert values into another table  i get this error

```
Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'TransactionDescriptionPK' doesn't have a default value
```

shouldn't the column automatically get the primary key from the other table ?

my query '

```
    'INSERT INTO Transaction '+
              'SET TransactionID = ?, TransactionDate = ?, Amount = ?, TransactionDescriptionPK = ?, FilePK = ?',
[transId,date,amount,"primary key to the TransactionDescription table","primary key to the File table"]
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  Constraints aren't there to provide data to a program, they are there to prevent a program / user from inserting invalid data into a table.  That's why they are called constraints.  You will need to either pull, insert or update the values in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a foreign key will not get a value from another table automatically. How should mysql figure out, which TransactionDescriptionPK value it should get from the parent table? You have to provide a value to all foreign key fields that are declared as not null and have no default value, just as you do for any other similar field.

Side note: if a field is declared as pk, you do not have to creat an unique index on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your error has anything to do with foreign keys.  You have a column `TransactionDescriptionPK` in your `TransactionDescription` table, which has been set to be `not null`, but you haven't provided any value for it in this insert statement.

Comment: then how do i add the foreign key?

Comment: I don't think you understand what a foreign key is.  The foreign key only checks to make sure that the values in your second (child) table have a corresponding row in the first (parent) table.  A foreign key does not automatically add data to your child table when a new parent table row is inserted.